# Combining two or more Object Lists together

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

This should simple but for some unknown reason it is erroring on me.

Database contains string SubjectId, bool QReport, int Q, int FY, List ANotes, int Id.
Id is the key column so is not retrieved.

I get data from a database table like

```
var unotesxx = db.UNotesDB.First(X => x.SubjectId == model.SubjectId);
```

This gets the data. I then put it into a object List.

```
List<UNotesDB> UNotes = new List<UNotes>();
Unotes.Add(unotesxx);
```

This works great. I have two Objects and Lists that use the same content. The difference is the data contained. Now I want to combine the two into a single List.

```
List<TNotesDB> TNotes = new List<TNotes>();
```

This one is setup exactly like the other two. I then tried

```
List<UNotesDB> UNotes = new List<UNotes>();
List<CNotesDB> CNotes = new List<CNotes>();
List<TNotesDB> TNotes = new List<TNotes>();
var unotesxx = db.UNotesDB.First(X => x.SubjectId == model.SubjectId);
var cnotesxx = db.UNotesDB.First(X => x.SubjectId == model.SubjectId);
UNotes.Add(unotesxx);
CNotes.Add(cnotesxx);
```

This all works, complies, and when I run Debug, everything looks great.

Now I want to combine the first two into the third one. So I added the next two statemens.

```
TNotes.Add(unotesxx);
TNotes.Add(cnotesxx);
```

These end up underlined in RED.

So I tried

```
for ( int i = 0; i < UNotes.Count; i++)
{
    TNotes.Add(UNotes[i]);
}
```

Again the ADD part is underlined in Red.
I know there is a simple reason this is not working, but for some reason, I can not see the
forest for the trees. LOL

Comment: Did you mean to write   TNotes.Add( ... );

Comment: You seem to be using TNotes as both a generic type parameter name.***and*** a local variable name; surely the latter is the error?

Comment: Yes that is a typo, it should read TNotes.Addd(.....)

Comment: All I want to do is simply combine UNotes and CNotes into TNotes. The Lists are the same so why would not the .ADD feature not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic List is strongly typed. You cannot add UNotesDB to a `List<TNotesDB>`.

Options:

1. Create a common "container" class for all three and load the various types into that container object and then into the list

   ```
   public class Note {
      public int SubjectID {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
   }

   //get UNOTE logic here...
   // then add unote to List. Repeat for other types.

   var note = new Note() {
      SubjectID = unote.SubjectID,
      Name = unote.Name,
   };

   noteList.Add(note);
   ```
2. Create an interface for all types and then create a list of that interface
3. Create a base type for all types and then create a list of that base type.

Assuming your database types are being generated by LINQ To SQL or the Entity Framework, the first option might be your simplest approach.

Comment: I gorgot all about Strongly typed. Once I read this, it was the old slap on the forehead for not remembering this. Thanks all